# Can't get it to work - Admin grid ui inline editor

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I can't get the inline editing to work in my custom admin UI component grid. It looks like I am missing an important point. Any help would be nice, also a hint how to debug it. I am trying to make the column "customer_email" editable.

**You can find the xml here:**

- https://gist.github.com/gewaechshaus/1f157991165a372634f4b346f2b11e15

Editor Config

- https://gist.github.com/gewaechshaus/1f157991165a372634f4b346f2b11e15#file-gewaechshaus_uwp_index_listing-xml-L134

Field Action

- https://gist.github.com/gewaechshaus/1f157991165a372634f4b346f2b11e15#file-gewaechshaus_uwp_index_listing-xml-L151

Editable Column

- https://gist.github.com/gewaechshaus/1f157991165a372634f4b346f2b11e15#file-gewaechshaus_uwp_index_listing-xml-L223

**I followed this tutorial:**

- https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-code-inline-editing-grid-in-magento-2-backend/#code_inline_editing_grid_in_magento_2_backend

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: Best solution to debug your issue is try to compare your xml file with the CMS block grid file and then you will get hint that which line/code is missing in your xml file.

Comment: Many thanks - I got it working... I renamed some nodes to shorten them and reorganised some stuff in the xml. I will post the result in a new gist as soon as I am ready.